# Is social media engagement really opinion-based?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I’ve asked a question about whether social media engagement is increasing and it has been closed as opinion-based. I can’t understand what is opinion-based about this question. Can somebody explain it to me please?

The original question is:
[Is social media engagement increasing?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153714/is-social-media-engagement-increasing)

Comment: Despite the close reason displayed the question is not a good fit for this site. Please checkout [help/on-topic] and [ask]. Tl;Dr questions on this site should be about using an specific web application.